# Is this considered to be "Internal Near-Duplicates"?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, duplicate-content, http, google-ranking

Some people generate the same pages with a slight variation in keywords, title, country name, region name, etc... This is typically considered to be "Internal Near-Duplicates."

I have seen a website generating pages that most would call near duplicated content using ID's as parameters:

```
   http://www.mysite.com/mypage.html?param=1
   http://www.mysite.com/mypage.html?param=2
   http://www.mysite.com/mypage.html?param=3
   http://www.mysite.com/mypage.html?param=4
   ...
```

Although only one HTML page is involved, is this still considered to be "Internal Near-Duplicates"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. With the changes that Panda brought, Google will recognize "Internal Near-Duplicates", that is pages which differ in only a few variations. See this link for more on that: [Panda Mistakes: Internal Near-Duplicates](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/are-you-making-these-7-panda-punishing-content-mistakes/38807/)

The use of [URL parameters](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1235687) would not avoid this. See these for more on that also:

[What is Duplicate Content:  URL Parameters](http://moz.com/learn/seo/duplicate-content)

[Duplicate content: causes and solutions - URL Parameters](http://yoast.com/articles/duplicate-content/#session-id)